# What kind of espresso tests can be performed on a recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have been performing UI tests and so far so good, my challenge at the moment is performing test on a recyclerView adapter class. I do not have the slightest idea of what kind of test can be done. My code is below.

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <HomeAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

   private Context mCtx;

   private List <HomeProduct> homeProductList;

   public HomeAdapter(Context context, List <HomeProduct> homeProductList) {
    this.mCtx = context;
    this.homeProductList = homeProductList;
}

@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_item_layout, null);
    return new ProductViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    final HomeProduct product = homeProductList.get(position);
    final String title = product.getTitle();
    final String subtitle = product.getSubtitle();

    holder.homeImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mCtx, product.getImage()));
    holder.homeTitleTextView.setText(product.getTitle());
    holder.homeSubtitleTextView.setText(product.getSubtitle());

    holder.homeLinearlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intentRoomActivity = new Intent(mCtx, RoomActivity.class);
            intentRoomActivity.putExtra("room_title", title);
            intentRoomActivity.putExtra("room_state", subtitle);
            mCtx.startActivity(intentRoomActivity);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return homeProductList.size();
}

class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView homeTitleTextView, homeSubtitleTextView;
    ImageView homeImageView;
    LinearLayout homeLinearlayout;

    public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        homeTitleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_title_textView);
        homeSubtitleTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_subtitle_textView);
        homeImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.home_imageView);
        homeLinearlayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeLinearLayout);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use Robolectric to the make that kind of test, the class must be placed in the test directory folder of your Android Resource Directory for the test to be effective.

So from my situation, certain tests i could run using robolectric in my RoomAdapter class which of a recyclerView adapter are below. Remember to use the annotation and "test" to specify a block of code you want to perform your test on. Also when it comes to drawables I used shadowDrawable, examples are below in full.

Hope it helps someone, stay blessed.

```
import static junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals;


@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)

public class RoomAdapterTest {
    private Context context;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;

//        Intent intent = new Intent();
//        intent.putExtra("roomTitle", "Title");
//        intent.putExtra("roomState","Subtitle");

        }

    @Test
    public void postsRecycleViewHomeAdapter() {
        // Set up dummy data
        List<RoomProduct> roomProductList = Arrays.asList(
                new RoomProduct(0, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background,"Tap", "On" , 05f),
                new RoomProduct(1, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "Shower", "Running", 0.5f),
                new RoomProduct(2, R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, "TV Channel", "53", 0.5f)
        );

        RoomAdapter adapter = new RoomAdapter(context,roomProductList);

        RecyclerView rvParent = new RecyclerView(context);
        rvParent.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

        // Run test On onBindViewHolder and ViewHolder on dummy data
        RoomAdapter.ItemViewAdapterHolder viewHolder = adapter.onCreateViewHolder(rvParent, 0);

        //Test number 1
        adapter.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, 0);
        assertEquals("Tap", viewHolder.roomItem.getText());
        assertEquals("On", viewHolder.roomState.getText());
        ShadowDrawable shadowDrawable = Shadows.shadowOf(viewHolder.roomImageItem.getDrawable());
        assertEquals(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, shadowDrawable.getCreatedFromResId());


        //Test number 2
        adapter.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder,1);
        assertEquals("Shower", viewHolder.roomItem.getText());
        assertEquals("Running", viewHolder.roomState.getText());
        ShadowDrawable shadowDrawable1 = Shadows.shadowOf(viewHolder.roomImageItem.getDrawable());
        assertEquals(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, shadowDrawable1.getCreatedFromResId());

        //Test number 3
        adapter.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, 2);
        assertEquals("TV Channel", viewHolder.roomItem.getText());
        assertEquals("53", viewHolder.roomState.getText());
        ShadowDrawable shadowDrawable2 = Shadows.shadowOf(viewHolder.roomImageItem.getDrawable());
        assertEquals(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background, shadowDrawable2.getCreatedFromResId());

    }
}
```

Comment: RuntimeEnvironment.application is deprecated. Alternative solution is  context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext() with Kotlin syntax

Answer (score 1):

Import `espresso-contrib` in Gradle and then [you have access to](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/RecyclerViewActions.html):

- actionOnHolderItem
- actionOnItem
- actionOnItemAtPosition
- scrollToHolder
- scrollToPosition

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your `HomeAdapter`, you can use [Roboelectric](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric) to mock a `RecyclerView` and then unit test the adapter methods. [Sample Code](https://github.com/codepath/android-robolectric-espresso-demo/blob/master/app/src/test/java/com.codepath.testingdemo/adapters/PostsAdapterTest.java)

```
package com.codepath.testingdemo.adapters;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.View;

    import com.codepath.testingdemo.BuildConfig;
    import com.codepath.testingdemo.models.Post;

    import org.junit.Before;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.robolectric.RobolectricGradleTestRunner;
    import org.robolectric.RuntimeEnvironment;
    import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    import static org.assertj.android.api.Assertions.assertThat;
    import static org.assertj.android.recyclerview.v7.api.Assertions.assertThat;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;


    @Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
    public class PostsAdapterTest {

        private Context context;

        @Before
        public void setup() {
            context = RuntimeEnvironment.application;
        }

        @Test
        public void postsAdapterViewRecyclingCaption() {
            // Set up input
            List<Post> posts = Arrays.asList(
                    new Post("Lebron", null),
                    new Post("Steph", "We Won!!!")
            );


            PostsRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new PostsRecyclerViewAdapter(posts);

            RecyclerView rvParent = new RecyclerView(context);
            rvParent.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));

            // Run test
            PostsRecyclerViewAdapter.PostItemViewHolder viewHolder =
                    adapter.onCreateViewHolder(rvParent, 0);

            adapter.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, 0);

            // JUnit Assertion
            assertEquals(View.GONE, viewHolder.tvCaption.getVisibility());

            // AssertJ-Android Assertion
            assertThat(viewHolder.tvCaption).isGone();

            adapter.onBindViewHolder(viewHolder, 1);

            // JUnit Assertion
            assertEquals("Steph: We Won!!!", viewHolder.tvCaption.getText().toString());

            // AssertJ-Android Assertion
            assertThat(viewHolder.tvCaption).isVisible().containsText("Won");

            assertThat(adapter).hasItemCount(2);
        }
    }
```